# Android: Switching between two activities

Tags: android

I have this code :

```
    Button groupsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.groupsButton);
    groupsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent myintentGroups=new Intent(CreateMessageActivity.this, GroupsActivity.class).putExtra("<StringName>", "Value");
            startActivityForResult(myintentGroups, 3);
        }
    });
```

and now I want to write the onActivityResult, I tried adding this code inside the onClick but it's not working (Eclipse gives me an error):

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String result_string=data.getStringExtra("<StringName>");
    }
```

Is the code for writing onActivityResult wrong or maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place ?

** Edit : ** the code :

```
        Button groupsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.groupsButton);
    groupsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent myintentGroups=new Intent(CreateMessageActivity.this, GroupsActivity.class).putExtra("<Came From Create Message>", "Value");
            startActivityForResult(myintentGroups, 3);
        }
    });

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String result_string=data.getStringExtra("<StringName>");
    }
```

Edit 2: The errors:
 Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
    - void is an invalid type for the variable 
     onActivityResult
    - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
    - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
    - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onActivityResult should be placed in the Activity class that contains the onClick not in the actual onClick. The CreateMessageActivity.this in the new Intent will indicate which activity the result should be returned to.

Comment: Eclipse gives me an error : void is an invalid type for the variable onActivityResult

Comment: oh, then you're probably not putting it in the right place... it should be in the body of your class, at the same level (sibling of) as onCreate

Comment: @Dr.Dredel - it's in the Activity class that contains the onClick

Comment: well... the code you have, as posted, is correct... so, you'll need to post more code, cause as is you should not be seeing any errors

Comment: Just to be clear the onActivityResult should be a standalone function in the Activity class. It should not be included inside of any function already in the class.

Comment: @Bobbake4 - my bad, it was in the OnCreate method

Comment: ah good... well... my answer (regarding where you're getting the data from) will come in handy momentarily :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are returning to this activity? What do you do in your GroupsActivity.class? How do you exit from it? The way to get back to THIS activity would be to call finish() in the GroupsActivity.class... then you should get your string.  If you are calling another startActivity() in your GroupsActivity.class then you're actually not coming "back" to THIS one, you're going forward to another instance of it.

also, in your displayed code you're not doing anything with the string... are you sure it's not already working correctly?